# Python. Replace "\\uxxxx" to "\uxxxx"

Tags: python, regex, unicode, replace

I'm scraping a web, and I get Unicode characters as raw.
Instead of getting the "ó" character, I get `\u00f3`.

It is the same as write:

```
>>>print("\\u00f3")
```

I want to convert `"\\u00f3"` into `"\u00f3"` in all unicode characters. It is:

```
"\\uxxxx" -> "\uxxxx"
```

But if I try to replace `\\` by `\`, next characters are interpreted as escape characters.

How can I do it?

---

Applying the next code, I can convert part of the characters:

```
def raw_to_utf8(matcher): 
    string2convert = matcher.group(0)
    return(chr(int(string2convert[2:],base=16)))

def decode_utf8(text_raw):
   text_raw_re=re.compile(r"\\u[0-9a-ce-z]\w{0,3}")
   return text_raw_re.sub(raw_to_utf8, text_raw)

text_fixed = decode_utf8(text_raw)
```

As you can see in the regular expression pattern, I have skipped the 'd' character. It is because \udxxx characters can't be converted in UTF-8 by this metod and any other one. They aren't important characters for me, so it is not a problem.

Thanks for your help.

************************** Solved ********************************

The best solution was solved previously:
[Python-encoding and decoding using codecs,unicode_escape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032035/python-encoding-and-decoding-using-codecs-unicode-escape)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is a function to print: https://repl.it/@blackskull12/DisfiguredMemorableStructs-8

Comment: What format is the website returning exactly? Is it by any chance also wrapped in `"double quotes"`? If so, it might be a JSON string you're dealing with; those often contain such sequences. In that case, you can simply use [`json.loads`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGrOD@Pi6ugKDOvRAPE1svJT0wp1sjMKygt0dDU1Pz/X8kjNScnptTAIM1YRyE8vygnRVEJAA) to convert the `\u` sequences to Unicode strings easily.

Comment: It is an instagram page:
https://www.instagram.com/forocochescom/
Im using requests to get the page, and Im trying to find how to change the codification, but actually I don't know how to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: maybe you are not decoding the webpage with the correct charset. If the web server does not supply the charset you might have to find it in the meta tags or make an educated guess. Maybe try a couple of usual charsets and compare the results.

Second: I played around with strings and decoding for a while and it's really frustrating, but I found a possible solution in `format()`:

```
s = "\\u00f3"
print('{:c}'.format(int(s[2:], 16)))
```

Format the extracted hex value as unicode seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace `'\\'` by `'\'` because `'\'` is not a valid literal string.

Convert the hexadecimal expression into a number, then find the corresponding character:

```
original = '\\u00f3'
char = chr(int(original[2:], base=16))
```

You can check that this gives the desired result:

```
assert char == '\u00f3'
```